# .hide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a jeopardy game. When I click a div I want to do some effect on it. However, I can't even get a simple .hide to work. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Jeopardy</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">        
        <link href="css/customStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">     
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/flip.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class ="container"> 
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="prizeAmount">                               
                    <div class="span2">     
                        <h3 id="test">100</h3>                          
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">     
                        <h3>100</h3>                                
                    </div>  
                    <div class="span2">     
                        <h3>100</h3>                                
                    </div>
                        <div class="span2">     
                            <h3>100</h3>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">     
                        <h3>100</h3>                        
                    </div>  
                    <div class="span2">     
                        <h3>100</h3>    
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--close container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {    
    $('#span2').click(function() {
        $(this).hide(400);
        /*$('#span2').hide(400);  <--tried this also */
    });
});
```

I've used jquery to animate navigation on a site before. Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Your using the ID selector instead of the class selector, try `.span2` instead

Comment: Refer to [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [jQuery Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the hash `#` which is the [id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) selector instead of the [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector which is a *dot* `.`.

Try

```
$(function() {    
    $('.span2').click(function() {
        $(this).hide(400);
     });
 });
```

You might want to read up more on the different jQuery Selectors on the official [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Just for reference, `#` is a hash, `#!` is a hash-bang.

Answer (score 5):

Your

```
$('#span2') // id selector
```

Should be

```
$('.span2') // class selector
```

Since it's a class

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any elements with ID "span2", they are all CLASS=span2.

Try this:

```
$(function() {    
 $('.span2').click(function() {
  $(this).hide(400);
 });
});
```

Note: this will effect ALL elements with the class "span2" if you don't want that behavior, then use ID="span2" for a single element, and use unique names for each.